# Solving a two-variable transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation and get `x` in terms of `y` or vice versa. However, I keep running into the same error message:

> ```
>  Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the
>  system obtained by direct rationalization...
> ```

```
Solve[2 x^2 (7.3 + E^(1. (2.5 - 1. x^2 - 0.5/(x^2 y^2) - 1. y^2)^2) (-35.6 + 
                     14.24 x^2 + 7.12/(x^2 y^2) + 14.24 y^2)) == 0 , x] // FullSimplify
```

How do I get *Mathematica* to solve this?

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that there is any reason to believe that a closed form expression exists for x or y here. `Solve`'s error message is essentially saying that. `Minimize` doesn't attempt to solve it either. If you have a guess as to the form of the solution, it may be possible to solve this with fitting methods.

Comment: There are exact solutions in terms of the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), see the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

**In general** when solving transcendental equations **one should not expect solutions in terms of radicals**, nethertheless **the equation at hand is quite special** since it can be transformed into a simpler form and this is the reason why **we can find solutions in terms of radicals involving special functions** and *Mathematica* allows reaching this goal with a bit more insightful approach than a very basic application of equation solving functionality of the system.

Since we are interested in exact solutions we should rewrite the equation in terms of exact numbers

```
Rationalize[2 x^2 (7.3 + E^(1. (2.5 - 1. x^2 - 0.5/(x^2 y^2) - 1. y^2)^2) (-35.6   
              + 14.24 x^2 + 7.12/(x^2 y^2) + 14.24 y^2)) == 0] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]
One can observe that that points $(x,y)$ where $x=0$ or $y=0$ don't belong to the domain of the given function and so we can recast the equation in a simpler form $g(x,y)=0$, where:

```
g[x_,y_]:= 73/10 + E^(5/2 - x^2 - 1/(2 x^2 y^2) - y^2)^2 (-(178/5) + 
          (356 x^2)/25 + 178/(25 x^2 y^2) + (356 y^2)/25)
```

Moreover we can see that the argument in the exponential function is simply related  to the one in the polynomial part:

```
(-(178/5) + (356 x^2)/25 + 178/(25 x^2 y^2) + (356 y^2)/25)/( 5/2 - x^2 
    - 1/(2 x^2 y^2) - y^2) // Simplify
```

> ```
>  -356/25
> ```

and so **we can define a new variable**: $z =\frac{5}{2} - x^2 - \frac{1}{2 x^2 y^2} - y^2\;$
and now we are looking for solutions $f(z)=0\;$ where

```
f[z_]:= 73/10 + E^z^2 (-356/25 z)
```

Now  we can expect infinitely many solutions and in order to find any of them we should restrict the domain of searching for solutions. It appears that e.g. a bound for `Abs[z]` is sufficient:

```
sol[p_] := SolveValues[73/10 + E^z^2 (-(356/25) z) == 0 && Abs[z] < p, z]
ComplexListPlot[sol[8], PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

and there is one real solution:

```
Reduce[73/10 + E^z^2 (-(356/25) z) == 0, z, Reals]
N @ %
```

> ```
> z == Sqrt[1/2 ProductLog[133225/253472]]  
> z == 0.427144
> ```

when we find $(x,y)$  it appears that there are four complex pairs respective to $z$:

```
Reduce[5/2 - x^2 - 1/(2 x^2 y^2) - y^2 == Sqrt[1/2 ProductLog[133225/253472]], x]
```

[image]

Solutions where $z$ is also complex have the same structure, the only difference is the argument of the `ProductLog` function.

Answer (score 1):

There no real number solutions, only have complex number solution.

```
eq=Rationalize[
  2 x^2 (7.3` + 
      E^(1.` (2.5` - 1.` x^2 - 0.5`/(x^2 y^2) - 1.` y^2)^2) (-35.6` + 
         14.24` x^2 + 7.12`/(x^2 y^2) + 14.24` y^2)) == 0, 0];
```

```
FindInstance[eq, {x, y}]
FindInstance[eq, {x, y}, Reals]
Reduce[eq, Reals]
NMinimize[First@eq, {x, y}]
```

[image]

All of above indicated that there no real solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Is there anyway to get Mathematica to show x in term of y?

Comment: @BEP  In present day **Mathematics** can't do this then **Mathematica** can't also.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  What do you mean?  Haven't just demonstrated  in my answer that can be done?